# Spring - How to consider multi-tenancy for Beans in Spring (multi client cabability)

Tags: java, spring, client, multi-tenant, thread-local

I have to write an application which need to be multi-tenant /multi-client capable (i.e. for each client context another database, different business logic beans and so on). It has to be possible to switch from one "client context" to another at runtime, therefore the right beans should be returned from spring context according the actual client context. Some information/ beans is kept client independent (i.e. some basic business logic, default implementation).

I am wondering how I can achieve this in spring without shutting down the application and using different bean definition files for each client context?

I saw for instance the solution to have ["Routed DataSource"](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) by using thread local context. But to write a "Bean Router" for each Bean type to make it "client context" specific looks for me too much overhead and I looking therefore for some support of the underlying spring framework.

- Is there a way / good example available how you consider multi-client/multi-tenancy support at runtime for beans with the spring framework?
- I not, Is there a way to extend the BeanFactory and BeanDefintions so it takes the Bean from a given "client context" which has been set  previously in a thread local? see example below

xml:

```
<bean name="silverClientDataSource" class="ch.megloff.common.datasource.DataSource"/>
<bean name="goldClientDataSource" class="ch.megloff.common.datasource.DataSource"/>
```

java:

```
ClientContext clientContext = applicationContext.getBean(ClientContext.class);
clientContext.switchContext("silverClient");
...
// get the datasource for silver Client
DataSource ds = applicationContext.getBean(DataSource.class);


ClientContext clientContext = applicationContext.getBean(ClientContext.class);
clientContext.switchContext("goldClient");
...
// get the datasource for gold Client
DataSource ds = applicationContext.getBean(DataSource.class);
// get oter beans for gold Client or return default implementation in case no context specific bean has been implemented
XXX bean =  applicationContext.getBean(XXX.class);
```

Comment: To switch out some logic according to credentials, use a strategy pattern. No need to load different application contexts. https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-strategy

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to overwrite an own beanFactory which allows me to use this kind of approach? I don't want to pass over in my code all the "strategy" parameter if I can retrieve it from a context i.e. ThreadLocal

Answer (score 0):

I started with a first dummy implementation, this may help to illustrate the behavior which I am looking for. This example uses not yet a BeanFactory from Spring, it just shows what the factory should do according the given context, see my dummy class ContextAwareBeanFactory. The factory is looking for beans of a specific type which implements the ContextAware interface and compars the value with a given context. The same approach could be achieved by using  annotation rather using an interface.

The next level would be to overwrite ApplicationContext and BeanFactory from Spring, so this approach can be used also for bean injection and autowired beans. Here I would appreciate if someone could point me into right direction and avoid me to oversee any pitfalls. Feel free to comment if you see other approaches or framwork tricks which I am not aware of. Thanks.

```
@Log4j2
public class TestContextAware extends TestBase {

  @Test
  public void testContextAware() {
    Context<String> clientContext = new ThreadLocalContext<String>();       
    ContextAwareBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getBean(ContextAwareBeanFactory.class);
    beanFactory.setContext(clientContext);

    clientContext.setValue("silver");
    AbstractTestBean bean = beanFactory.getBean(AbstractTestBean.class);
    log.info(bean);

    clientContext.setValue("gold");
    bean = beanFactory.getBean(AbstractTestBean.class);
    log.info(bean);

  }
}
```

console output

```
23:47:37.393 INFO - TestBean1@566e142
23:47:37.589 INFO - TestBean2@3b24087d
```

further classes:

```
public static abstract class AbstractTestBean implements ContextAware {
    Object contextValue;
    @Override
    public void setContextValue(Object value) {
        contextValue = value;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getContextValue() {
        return contextValue;
    }
}

@Component
public static class TestBean1 extends AbstractTestBean {
    public TestBean1() {
        setContextValue("silver");
    }
}

@Component
public static class TestBean2 extends AbstractTestBean {
    public TestBean2() {
        setContextValue("gold");
    }
}


@Component
public class ContextAwareBeanFactory {
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
  @Setter
  private Context<?> context;
  public <T> T getBean(Class<T> type) {
    Object contextValue = context.getValue();
    // check if bean implements "ContextAware" interface and if it matches the value
    if (contextValue != null) {
        Map<String,T> beans = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(type);
        for(T bean : beans.values()) {
            if (bean instanceof ContextAware) {
                if (contextValue.equals(((ContextAware)bean).getContextValue())) {
                    return bean;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return applicationContext.getBean(type);
  }
}

@Component
public class ThreadLocalContext<T> implements Context<T> {
  private static ThreadLocal<Object> holder =  new InheritableThreadLocal<Object>();
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public T getValue() {
    return (T)holder.get();
  }
  public void setValue(T value) {
    holder.set(value);
  }
  public void clear() {
    holder.remove();
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: I found a first interesting link how to extend the ApplicationContext and BeanFactory to detect implementation class at runtime [link](http://develop.nydi.ch/2010/12/30/spring-primary-bean-injection/)

Comment: some other frameworks as hybris are using an own custom scope e.g. scope="tenant", but this would not work for my approach  because the "Scope.get(..)" method get called after the bean has been already selected (during collecting the candidates), so if then multiple beans get found you get not unique bean of type exception

Answer (score 0):

After studying several approaches I came to the conclusion that the easiest solution for my problem is to use the ["Priority" / "Order"](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) feature in Spring to influence which implementation you like to retrieve at runtime for your bean with "getBean(Class type)".

Overwriting the ApplicationContext is not recommended because for this class exists serveral types of Implementation and they don't offer to set the BeanFactory. This would mean you need to overwrite all types of ApplicationContext classes to be on safe side and this is dangerous if the core framework of spring is changing or get updated.

The only sophisticated and most flexible approach I foud was to use an own implementation of a "BeanFactoryPostProcessor". This allows to set ["DependencyComparator"](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.html#setDependencyComparator-java.util.Comparator-) on the "DefaultListableBeanFactory" which is used to evaluate "Priority" / "Order" of the candidate Beans.

Please find here an example how this can look like:

spring.xml

```
<bean id="tenantContext" class="ThreadLocalContext"></bean>
<bean class="ContextAwareBeanFactoryPostProcessor">
    <property name="context" ref="tenantContext"></property>
</bean>
```

classes

```
public class ContextAwareBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

  ContextAwareComparator ContextAwareComparator = new ContextAwareComparator(); 

  public void setContext(Context<?> context) {
    ContextAwareComparator.setContext(context);
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
      if (beanFactory instanceof DefaultListableBeanFactory) {     
((DefaultListableBeanFactory)beanFactory).setDependencyComparator(ContextAwareComparator);
      }
  } 
}

public class ContextAwareComparator extends AnnotationAwareOrderComparator {

  @Setter
  private Context<?> context;

  public Integer getPriority(Object obj) {
      if (context != null && obj != null) {
        Object value = context.getValue();
        if (value !=  null) {
            if (obj instanceof ContextAware) {
                    if (value.equals(((ContextAware)obj).getContextValue())) {
                        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
                    }
            }
        }
      }
      return super.getPriority(obj);
    }
}
```

I hope that in the future Spring "DefaultListableBeanFactory" get extendend to allow a tenancy support.